# ¿Qué interjecciones tiene registradas el DLE que hayan caído ya en desuso?

Tags: historia, dle, interjecciones

El idioma español tiene un nutrido grupo de interjecciones (646 me aparecen en la búsqueda entre interjecciones y locuciones interjectivas), de lo más variado y colorido. Sin embargo, muchas habrá que nos habremos dejado por el camino. ¿Cuáles son estas interjecciones y locuciones interjectivas históricas que se han perdido hoy día?

Answer (score 1):

En la edición 23.2 (actualización 2018) del DLE aparecen las siguientes:

> **[aba](https://dle.rae.es/?id=009ISzT)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. cuidado.
>
> **[absit](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0CO0Aph)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Manifiesta el rechazo de quien habla hacia algo que considera pernicioso o negativo.
>
> **[ahó](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1HcuXPn)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Era u. entre los campesinos para llamarse de lejos.
>
> **[alón<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=23gaK0V)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Era u. para excitar a mudar de lugar, de ejercicio o asunto.
>
> **[arre allá](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3geCpGQ)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. coloq. desus. Manifiesta desprecio o enfado, y se emplea para rechazar a alguien.
>
> **[ax](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4b0jNyn)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Era u. para expresar dolor.
>
> **[aymé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4cDp3Z3)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Ay de mí.
>
> **[buenas y gordas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6EawoZ6)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. coloq. desus. Era u. para desdeñar cualquier asunto muy trillado, falso o absurdo.
>
> **[ce<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=849O3jw)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar, hacer detener o pedir atención a alguien.
>
> **[chite<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8ud51f2)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. chitón (‖ para imponer silencio).
>
> **[cierra, España](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GUQ1mFn)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. Era u. en la antigua milicia para animar a los soldados y hacer que acometiesen con valor al enemigo.
>
> **[ésbate](https://dle.rae.es/?id=G4lJUFS)**
>
> 1. interj. germ. Era u. para pedirle a alguien que se esté quieto.
>
> **[es obra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QnrhaT6)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. desus. ya es obra.
>
> [**favor a la justicia,** o **favor al rey**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HgrAoQO)
>
> 1. locs. interjs. desus. Eran u. por los ministros de justicia para pedir ayuda y socorro para aprehender a un delincuente.
>
> **[grado a Dios](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JOxOtbx)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. desus. gracias a Dios.
>
> **[gualá](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Je8W9JT)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. por Dios.
>
> **[guarte](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JlHvsDt)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. guarda.
>
> **[guay<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JmihBh3)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. poét. ay.
>
> **[guayas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JnYUO4z)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. ay.
>
> **[guerra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JoNxOnS)**
>
> 6. interj. Era u. para excitarse al combate.
>
> **[ha](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JutKz3R)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. ah (‖ para denotar pena, admiración o sorpresa).
>
> **[hao](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K0hEqfF)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a alguien que estuviese distante.
>
> **[harre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K2MgBOH)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. arre (‖ para estimular a las bestias).
>
> **[he<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K3tgQNM)**
>
> 2. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a alguien.
>
> **[hola](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KYtLWBc)**
>
> 3. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a los inferiores.
>
> **[hu](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Kiw9fZb)**
>
> 1. interj. Era u. repetida tres veces en las galeras para saludar a las personas principales que entraban en ellas.
>
> **[hum](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KnEraiH)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. uf.
>
> **[miz](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PRQFfrZ)**
>
> 2. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar al gato (‖ mamífero félido).
>
> [**monta,** o **montas**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PjOk949)
>
> 1. interjs. coloqs. desus. anda.
>
> **[oxte, puto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RNb8jNS)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. coloq. desus. oxte.
>
> **[palabra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RUl938s)**
>
> 14. interj. desus. Era u. para llamar a alguien a conversación.
>
> **[pardiobre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RuOXJSQ)**
>
> 1. interj. desus. par Dios.
>
> **[plaza](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TNxkfxk)**
>
> 11. interj. Era u. cuando salía el rey o en otras ocasiones de gran concurso para mandar a la gente que dejara libre el paso.
>
> **[vítor la ronca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WflK3ge)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. irón. desus. Era u. para señalar el desprecio hacia la amenaza o la jactancia del valor de alguien.
>
> **[voto a Cribas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BGAvibS)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. desus. voto a Cristo.
>
> **[voto a Cristo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BJidC1H)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. desus. Era u. para expresar ira, juramento o amenaza.
>
> **[voto a rus](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Wr6wU6C)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. coloq. desus. voto al chápiro.
>
> **[ya es obra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QnrhaT6)**
>
> 1. loc. interj. desus. Era u. para encarecer la dificultad, trabajo o molestia de algo.